# How to make the snowflake rotate more smoothly?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am new to python animation, although have managed to use animation to make the snowflake rotate but it is not rotating so smoothly...
I have attached the code below, can anyone please suggest me what do I do to make it rotate more smoothly?

```
import turtle
import time
bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.ht()
screen = turtle.Screen()
bob.speed(100)
screen.tracer(0, 0)
n = 0
bob.pencolor("blue")
bob.pensize(5)

def vshape():
  bob.rt(25)
  bob.fd(50)
  bob.backward(50)
  bob.lt(50)
  bob.fd(50)
  bob.backward(50)
  bob.rt(25)

def snowflakeArm():
  for x in range(4):
    bob.fd(30)
    vshape()
  bob.backward(120)
    
def snowflake(n, x, y):
  bob.seth(n)
  bob.pu()
  bob.setpos(x ,y)
  bob.pd()
  for x in range(6):
    snowflakeArm()
    bob.rt(60)

while True:
  time.sleep(0.02)
  bob.update()
  bob.clear()
  snowflake(n, 0, 0)
  snowflake(n, 350, 0)
  snowflake(n, -350, 0)
  snowflake(n, 0, 350)
  snowflake(n, 0, -350)
  n += 10
```

I have tried to decrease the sleep time as well as decrease the amount of rotation but still no result...

Comment: Reducing the amount of rotation (`n`) and decreasing the sleep time, as you suggest, makes the rotation pretty smooth for me. Can you explain what you feel is _not_ smooth about it?

Comment: @cemper93 What values have you kept for the amount of rotation(n) and the sleep time?

Comment: I removed the sleep entirely, put `oldt = time.time()` above your main loop and replaced `n += 10` with `t = time.time(); n += (oldt - t) * 20; oldt = t`. Honestly, though, even your posted code runs smoothly for me. Have you considered that your machine might not have the necessary processing power to render this at 50 FPS? Does reducing the amount of snowflakes improve the "smoothness"?

Comment: @cemper93 Actually I am just a beginner in python turtle animation and I haven't really checked if my system supports the necessary processing power...  What do you mean by oldt and what does this piece of code do?

Comment: the code ensures that the speed of rotation of the snowflake does not depend on how long it takes to render the snowflake. This way, the code produces similar results on different computers, even when they have different performance, and also subjectively feels less "laggy". See https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70255/what-is-framerate-independent-motion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It concerns me that you're able to call `bob.update()` successfully as `update()` isn't a method of `Turtle` in the standard turtle.py released with Python 3 nor Python 2.  You may be using an older, or non-standard, turtle implementation so some of the below may need to be adjusted.

Rather than introduce `time.sleep()`, which is out of sync with turtle's own event handler, let's use a turtle `ontimer()` event:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def vshape():
    turtle.right(25)
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.backward(50)
    turtle.left(50)
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.backward(50)
    turtle.right(25)

def snowflakeArm():
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(30)
        vshape()

    turtle.backward(120)

def snowflake(angle, position):
    turtle.setheading(angle)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(position)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(360 // 60):
        snowflakeArm()
        turtle.right(60)

angle = 0

def snowflakes():
    global angle

    turtle.clear()

    snowflake(angle, (0, 0))
    snowflake(angle, (350, 0))
    snowflake(angle, (-350, 0))
    snowflake(angle, (0, 350))
    snowflake(angle, (0, -350))

    screen.update()

    angle = (angle + 10) % 360

    screen.ontimer(snowflakes, 25)  # repeat 25 milliseconds from now

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.pencolor('blue')
turtle.pensize(5)

snowflakes()

screen.exitonclick()
```

This should also allow us to exit the program cleanly, by clicking on the window, without generating all those warning messages.